# Solving the Diophantine equation $9923w -9187x +9011y +9973z = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Take the following Diophantine equation.

$$9923w -9187x +9011y +9973z = 0$$

Mathematica solves this as:

$$y = 9973 n + 4437 w + 6843 x, z = -9011 n - 4010 w - 6182 x, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

How can you do this by hand?

Comment: Note that, for example, $\gcd(9011,9973)=1$ so you know the integer solutions of $9011y+9973z=k$ for any integer $k$ is given by ...

Answer (score 1):

A reduced basis for your lattice is given by the rows of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  3 & 17 & -7 & 19\\
  7 & -6 & -26 & 11\\
 -19 & -11 & -8 & 16\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Given a triple of integer coefficients $a,b,c,$  the linear combination  is  the matrix product

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
  a & b & c \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  3 & 17 & -7 & 19\\
  7 & -6 & -26 & 11\\
 -19 & -11 & -8 & 16\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Apologies for my basic questions but first, how can you compute the reduced basis?

Comment: And second, how does [3+7−19, 17−6−11, −7−26−8, 19+11+16] give you the answer that Mathematica provides?

Comment: @Anush  I can't make out what the Mathematica answer means. If you can work out three (independent) integer vectors from that, you can then check whether all three are linear combinations of my three... As far as how I began, i used elementary column operations to take the initial quadruple to $(1,0,0,0).$   In the 4 by 4 matrix expressing those operations, call it $R,$       the left column is ignored, the next three columns give a basis for the lattice.

Comment: I think it means that $w, x$ and $n$  can be chosen to be any integers and from there you make $y$ and $z$ using the given formulas.